# Rails rendering partials even when commented out

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, partials

I'm curious how Rails 5 renders partials and if there's a gotcha that I'm not aware of. I have two partials on my page, one that is rendered as part of the html and the other that renders inside the success callback of an ajax request. However, when I refresh the page, the partial inside the ajax request is actually being rendered even when the ajax request is not fired, and EVEN when the call to render the partial is commented out.

I had always assumed that partials render at the time the line of code is run.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
$('body').on("click", ".notif-popup-container", function() {

  $.post(
    "/notifications/read",
    { notif_id: notifId },
  ).done(function(data) {
    $('#notifUnreadCount').html(data.unread_notifs);
    
    var popover = $('#notificationsBell').data('bs.popover');
    popover.config.content = $('.notifications-list').html();
  })


  $('.notifications-list').html("<%= j (render partial: 'notifications/partials/test_partial') %>"); // this never fails to render, even when commented out

})
```

```html
<div style="display:none" class="notifications-list">
  <%= render 'notifications/partials/popover_notifications' %>
</div>
```

Here is the console output image. As you can see _popover_notifications.html.erb renders as it should, but then my _test_partial.html.erb also renders, which it shouldn't, since the click handler it's in was not fired.

[image: rails server output]

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Could you please grep 'test_partial' across the project, maybe you render it somewhere else? Maybe inside 'popover_notifications.html.erb '?

Comment: Hi @Vasilisa that's the only place I have it unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had always assumed that partials render at the time the line of code is run.

The key here is understanding when the code is run. When you dynamically create javascript with `js.erb` the file is first run through ERB on the server before it is sent to the client which runs the resulting javascript. Your server does not actually parse the javascript so it does not know or care that there is a event handler involved. To Rails its just a string buffer.

This is actually a major conceptual problem with `js.erb` templates as the context switching between server and client side makes the flow hard to follow.

There are also numerous other problems with this code like the use of the `===` identity operator and the fact that your performing DB queries in the view which is a huge anti-pattern.

Comment: Also turbolinks will replace the `body` element. If you want to delegate events do it from document.

Comment: Thanks @max, that makes sense. I am trying to set the 'content' of my bootstrap popover to the updated version of the partial, after the ajax call changes an "unread" notification to a "read" notification. How might I accomplish that? Also, another question: I see what you mean by performing db queries in the view -- how can I fix this? Another dev I was working in (who has more experience than me with rails, since I am fairly new) was using this pattern elsewhere, so I just followed it. Thanks again.

Comment: It depends on exactly what the change is. If its just a simple change in presentation (like graying it out) you just toggle a class on the element and do an optimistic update in the background. If you have to re-render the the whole thing in rails for some reason you would need to either return the rendered element as a JSON string or create a JS.erb template that replaces the element. This kind falls outside of the scope of your original question so please ask this as a separate question.

Comment: By performing DB queries in the view I mean exactly that. In that screenshot you have `<% unread_notifications = Notifications.unread(current_user) %>`. If you ever have worked on for example a Wordpress theme you can recognize why this is problematic - down the line you'll end up firing boatloads of db requests and your views which are already really messy since its a mix of html and ruby turn into a dumpster fire.

Comment: If you query the data needed upfront in the controller its easy to get an overview and optimize the queries with joins and eager loading so that you don't end up with N+1 query issues. Its also a tenant of good MVC design which your college does seem to understand. https://jasoncharnes.com/remove-activerecord-views/

Comment: all great points, thank you. That article you linked was very helpful. Regarding the separate question, I've asked a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208681/rails-update-bootstrap-popover-content-with-partial-after-ajax -- would appreciate your insight if you are so inclined.