# Rails - update bootstrap popover content with partial after ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building out a notifications feature using bootstrap popover. When a user clicks on a notification, it will mark that notification as read through an ajax call. On ajax success, I want to replace the content of the popover with the updated version. Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#notificationsBell").popover({
    'title' : $('.notifications-title-header').html(),
    'html' : true,
    'placement' : 'left',
    'content' : $(".notifications-list").html()
  }); 
});

$('#notificationsBell').off("click").on("click", function() {
  $("#notificationsBell").popover('toggle');
})

$(document).on("click", ".notif-popup-container", function() {
  // 1. get correct id for clicked notification
  var notifId = $(this).attr("id");

  // 2. Update the notification to be read and show update
  $.post(
    "/notifications/read",
    { notif_id: notifId },
  ).done(function(data) {
    $('#notifUnreadCount').html(data.unread_notifs);
    
  // 3. Replace html content of hidden div with updated notifications
  $('.notifications-list').html("<%= j (render partial: 'notifications/partials/test_partial') %>");
    
  // 4. Set popover content to be that div's html
  var popover = $('#notificationsBell').data('bs.popover');
  popover.config.content = $('.notifications-list').html();
})
```

```html
# what is originally stored in the popover 

<div style="display:none" class="notifications-list">
  <%= render 'notifications/partials/popover_notifications' %>
</div>

# _popover_notifications.html.erb
# this is rendered twice, once above and once on ajax success

<% unread_notifications = Notification.unread_count(current_user) %>
<% if unread_notifications.eql? 0 %>
    No notifications to display! You are up to date.
<% else %>
    <% notifs = current_user.notifications.where(read_at: nil).order("created_at DESC") %>
    <% notifs.each do |notif| %>
        <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display" id=<%= notif.id %> >
          <b><p><%= notif.notify_type %></p></b>
          <span class="n-date trans-timestamp dateTime" data-momentiz="(<%= notif.momentize %>)"></span>
          <p><%= notif.message %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This content is displayed via a partial. However, this is where the issue arises. Though I expected the partial in the ajax success callback to be rendered at the time of the ajax success, it recently learned that the rendering of the partial is done first by the server (before any js is even run), then the result of that is passed back to the javascript.

So effectively, both partials render on page load, which means I can no longer dynamically set the popover content through the partial rendering dynamically after ajax success.

My question is, is there a way around this that would allow me to dynamically render the partial instead of it being populated into the js on page load? Or if not, possibly a completely different approach -- I am open to any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You could just `.append()` it via JS, once you get the data back from the server, construct the same HTML in the partial and append the data of the object to the html then append it to `notifications-list`

Comment: Hi @ricks so do you mean instead of rendering the partial, just copy the code in the partial to the append() function? It seems like that way that code will be repeated.

Comment: Sorry, just posted an answer that should give you what you need, you need to fetch the partial with a controller so you can just append the HTML

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Yes, I am using turbolinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the partial from your controller like so:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def render_partial

    notification_id = params[:notification_id]

    # Fetch notification data
    notification = Notification.find(notification_id)

    # Return partial with new notification data
    render partial: 'notifications/partials/test_partial', locals: {:notification => notification}
  end
end
```

Then [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) the response in JS:

```
$('.notifications-list').append(resp)
```

Comment: You're the man ricks! Using another ajax call to a newly defined controller method similar to what you described above worked.